# Replace bunch of symbols in PHP

Tags: php, replace

I have a string with bunch of special characters/symbols and I want to replace them with some other strings. For example `$` should became `_dollar`, `,` should become `_comma`, `(` `_openparenthesis`, `)` `_closeparenthesis` and so on.

Is this the best approach or I can replace them all in "one move" *(*there are more symbols, I didn't put them all in here)*?

```
public function replaceSymbols() {
    $codedVersion = $this->getBody();

    $replacementArray = array(
        '$' => '_dollar',
        ',' => '_comma',
        '(' => '_openparenthesis',
        ')' => '_closeparenthesis',
        '[' => '_opensquarebrackets',
        ']' => '_closesquarebrackets',
        '{' => '_opencurlybrackets',
        '}' => '_closecurlybrackets'
    );

    foreach($replacementArray as $key => $value)
        $codedVersion = str_replace($key, $value, $codedVersion);

    return $codedVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the exact behavior you want using the function [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$codedVersion = $this->getBody();

$replacementArray = array(
    '$' => '_dollar',
    ',' => '_comma',
    '(' => '_openparenthesis',
    ')' => '_closeparenthesis',
    '[' => '_opensquarebrackets',
    ']' => '_closesquarebrackets',
    '{' => '_opencurlybrackets',
    '}' => '_closecurlybrackets'
);

$codedVersion = strtr($codedVersion, $replacementArray);
```

As the other answers state it's also possible to do this in one `str_replace` call using `array_keys` and `array_values`, but besides the more straightforward syntax there's an important functional difference between the two: `strtr` will leave already replaced strings untouched (i.e. the search/replace pairs won't interfere with eachother), and `str_replace` won't. Consider this example ([demo](http://codepad.org/8Wf5PzSC)):

```
$replacementArray = array(
    '$' => '_dollar',
    '_' => '_underscore'
);

$codedVersion = '$';

// strtr() returns string(7) "_dollar" as expected
var_dump(strtr($codedVersion, $replacementArray));

// str_replace() replaces twice, so returns string(17) "_underscoredollar"
var_dump(str_replace(array_keys($replacementArray), array_values($replacementArray), $codedVersion));
```

This can cause weird bugs very easily when the replacement array hasn't been carefully ordered, and some multi-replace operations aren't even possible with `str_replace` while they are possible with `strtr`. For these reasons I would recommend using `strtr` unless the `str_replace` behavior is explicitly needed.

Comment: This would be the cleanest way

Answer (score 3):

`str_replace` is the best method for this, you can just pass the 2 arrays as the 2 parameters though so you only have to call it once...

```
$codedVersion = str_replace(array('$', ','), array('_dollar', '_comma'), $codedVersion);
```

Comment: I would say @Another Code's way - using `strtr` - is cleaner than this

Comment: What about this solution versus @Another Code with strtr?

Comment: @svenkapudija the syntax is different (`strtr` uses the format your array is already in, `str_replace` wants the search and replace values in seperate arrays), but there's also an important functional difference. Check my updated answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the loop and do

```
return str_replace(array_keys($replacementArray), array_values($replacementArray), $codedVersion);
```

This will do the replace operation and return the result in one go.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `str_replace` two arrays - one of matches, the other of replacements. You can use `array_keys` and `array_values` to get these from your `$replacementArray`:

```
$codedVersion = str_replace(array_keys($replacementArray), array_values($replacementArray), $codedVersion);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public function replaceSymbols() {
    $codedVersion = $this->getBody();

    $replacementArray = array(
        '$' => '_dollar',
        ',' => '_comma',
        '(' => '_openparenthesis',
        ')' => '_closeparenthesis',
        '[' => '_opensquarebrackets',
        ']' => '_closesquarebrackets',
        '{' => '_opencurlybrackets',
        '}' => '_closecurlybrackets'
    );

    $codedVersion = str_replace(array_keys($replacementArray), array_values($replacementArray), $codedVersion);

    return $codedVersion;
}
```